# Form does not show when "Me.Opacity = 100" is used during form load

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I tried many different methods to make this form work properly.
What I am trying to achieve here is to have the Form show itself for two seconds before it closes when the function returns a false boolean and shows two other forms when the function returns true.
I am having difficulties as when the function returns a true boolean the application does its job and shows the other two forms and hides itself. But when it receives a false boolean it doesn't show itself and it doesn't exit (As seen in the task manager processes).

Form Code:

```
Public Class SimpleSplash

Private Sub SimpleSplash_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Refresh()
    If functions.CheckForInternetConnection() = False Then
        Me.Opacity = 100
        functions.sleep(2000)
        Application.Exit()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        Form1.persistentcheck = True
        drmtime.Show()
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

functions.CheckForInternetConnection()

```
Public Shared Function CheckForInternetConnection() As Boolean


    Dim url As String


    url = "http://www.google.com/"
    Dim FoundStatus As Boolean = False

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) Then Return False
    If url.Equals("about:blank") Then Return False

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse

    request = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Timeout = 5000

    Try
        response = request.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True


End Function
```

Comment: `Opacity` is a `Double` from 0 to 1, not 0 to 100.

Comment: How are you hiding the form?

Comment: The window is not yet visible when the Load event fires.  So you can't see anything.  You'd have to use the Shown event instead.  Never call Sleep() on the UI thread, use a Timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling Me.Show() when the result is false. So the form is at 100 opacity, but not shown.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the form that starts this form has the following code 

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rgJdKEdE

Comment: My apologies then. If you're already 'showing' it, it doesn't need to be 'shown' again. Hans' comment on the question (re: load event) is probably the best path to follow at this point.